# How can I check if address property is null or not in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I check that if the address is null or not? if address is null set city,state and country as a black string. the code is like this,

```
const getOrdersData = (
  data: OrderDataProps
): [] | {} => {
  return data.map(
    ({
      transactionDetail: {
        orderedAtUserTz,
        amountInCents: { total },
        status,
        contactByContactId: {
          emailAddresses,
          gender,
          address: { city, state, country },
          name: { firstName, fullName },
        },
        items,
      },
      id,
      settledAmount,
    }: Transaction) => ({ 
      date: [orderedAtUser],
      amount: [settledAmount, status],
      location: [city, state, country],
      customer: [
        firstName || fullName,
        emailAddresses && emailAddresses[0] ? emailAddresses[0].email : '',
        gender,
      ],
      products: items,
      id,
    })
  )
}
```

if the address is null it will throw error like `can't read property city of null.`

Comment: Let's switch this chat to discord? https://discord.gg/programming . Go to the #javascript and talk.

Answer (score 1):

First of all when using interface make sure you pass arguments are per interface structure, or else
there won't be any point of using such type-strict interfaces.
Assuming this, your address should not be
null, it should be an object with keys having blank strings or atleast an empty object.

So if we have blank object, considering this, passing a default value as blank string makes sense. No change in callback function required but might have to change `Transaction` interface properties.
so while destructuring in arguments
for eg :

```
{city = '', state ='', country=''}
```

If still we want to go ahead with `address` as `null` value. we need to validate in
the callback function. Need to maintain an `address` property instead of
destructuring it as `city, state` etc in arguments.
for eg :

```
{
      ...
      gender,
      address,
      ...
  }
```

In callback function, we need to validate and destructure it.

```
() =>{
      let location = []; // or ['','','']
      if(address){
        const {city, state, country} = address;  
        location = [city, state, country];
      }

      return {
          ...,
          location
          ...
      }
  }
```